# How to Prevent SWF from Decompiling?

Tags: flash, decompiling, actionscript-3, actionscript

How do I prevent my SWF from decompiling?

Is there any difference between ActionScript 1/2 and ActionScript 3 **in the perspective of decompile prevention**?

This is an opposite question of the following question:

> How do you decompile a swf file?
>   [How do you decompile a swf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97018/how-do-you-decompile-a-swf-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't avoid anyone from getting your source if they try hard enough.

You can use tools to make reading the code more difficult, however you won't make it harder to decompile. The decompiled output will simply be obfuscated.

The one reverse engineering can then try to deobfuscate your code, making it readable again. You can make it more difficult to deobfuscate your obfuscated code by using better obfuscation methods. Unfortunately there is little known about tools like [this one](http://www.kindisoft.com/secureSWF/actionscript-obfuscator.php), and thus we are forced to believe the words of the developers that created them. One of these answers is made in [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259821/any-reverse-engineers-have-experience-with-secureswf). But to be honest, this is not very reliable.

You would need to hire professional and experienced reverse engineers to try and deobfuscate one of these obfuscated files to really know howmuch time it will take them and whether it is going to be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.swftools.com/tools-category.php?cat=840

Here is a plenty of tools for SWF obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot prevent any client side tool including flash from being decompiled/hacked...etc. There are a lot of ways to hack flash and other client side tools including memory hack which doesnt even need to touch the swf to hack.

There are several tools for making decompiling harder like secureswf (http://www.kindi.com/) and swf encrypt (http://www.amayeta.com/). But neither worth the money is my opinion. The swf will still be decompilable but a little bit harder.

You shouldn't put sensitive data in the clientside or user serverside technology (like php) for validation and securing your data.